# Line Segments Intersect with shared starting and ending points

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to test if lines can be placed by seeing if they would intersect with any existing lines in a list.

```
public static bool onLine(Line l1, Vector2 p)
    {   //check whether p is on the line or not
        if (p.x <= Mathf.Max(l1.startingPoint.x, l1.endingPoint.x) && p.x <= Mathf.Min(l1.startingPoint.x, l1.endingPoint.x) &&
           (p.y <= Mathf.Max(l1.startingPoint.y, l1.endingPoint.y) && p.y <= Mathf.Min(l1.startingPoint.y, l1.endingPoint.y)))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public static int directionV2(Vector2 a, Vector2 b, Vector2 c)
    {
        float val = (b.y - a.y) * (c.x - b.x) - (b.x - a.x) * (c.y - b.y);
        if (val == 0)
            return 0;     //colinear
        else if (val < 0)
            return 2;    //anti-clockwise direction
        return 1;    //clockwise direction
    }

    public static bool isIntersect(Line l1, Line l2)
    {
        //four direction for two lines and points of other line
        int dir1 = directionV2(l1.startingPoint, l1.endingPoint, l2.startingPoint);
        int dir2 = directionV2(l1.startingPoint, l1.endingPoint, l2.endingPoint);
        int dir3 = directionV2(l2.startingPoint, l2.endingPoint, l1.startingPoint);
        int dir4 = directionV2(l2.startingPoint, l2.endingPoint, l1.endingPoint);

        if (dir1 != dir2 && dir3 != dir4)
            return true; //they are intersecting

        if (dir1 == 0 && onLine(l1, l2.startingPoint)) //when p2 of line2 are on the line1
            return true;

        if (dir2 == 0 && onLine(l1, l2.endingPoint)) //when p1 of line2 are on the line1
            return true;

        if (dir3 == 0 && onLine(l2, l1.startingPoint)) //when p2 of line1 are on the line2
            return true;

        if (dir4 == 0 && onLine(l2, l1.endingPoint)) //when p1 of line1 are on the line2
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

```
    public struct Line
{
    public Vector2 startingPoint;
    public Vector2 endingPoint;

    public Line(Vector2 start, Vector2 end)
    {
        this.startingPoint = new Vector2(start.x, start.y);
        this.endingPoint = new Vector2(end.x, end.y);
    }
}
```

This is what I've managed to gather so far through other posts but I'm struggling adjusting it to include that two lines can share the same starting position without it being intersecting.

Update: I figured that adding the conditions l1.startingPoint != p && l1.endingPoint != p would be the solution. The code however seems to still be producing intersecting lines. I'm uncertain if my solution is wrong or if I'm creating the issue in a different part of code.

Update Update: included Line struct

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Include the definition of the `Line` class.

Comment: @JAlex I have now, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Why are you using Vectors for Points?

Comment: @Fredy it was an already existing system to hold 2d coordinates so I figured I should use it. I don't know if it harms the code in anyway however

Comment: @Fredy - why not vectors? it is the preferred way anyway as their algebra is well defined, in contrast to `PointF` structures.

Comment: @JAlex I don't agree, words must reflect objects. If they aren't well defined, I'll make my own.

Comment: @iGeron1mo Harming the code, I don't know. But it's unreadable. JavaScript, python, C# in all these languages you don't have to comment your code. It must speak for itself. Thus my remark to JAlex above: code use words, these words must fit the reality. Keep on clarifying!

Comment: @Fredy - I agree on this point, that rolling your own `Point` structure can help, but it can also hurt. There are assumptions with points, like dimensionality, Euclidian or Projective (homogeneous) and there are cases where points are defined not with coordinates but other relationships.  So how do you define the addition of two points in homogeneous coordinates? This a problem with writing your own point struct.

So a vector makes it clear is just a container for 2 or 3 values that obeys the laws of vector algebra (addition and scaling) and the way thing are calculates is very clear.

Comment: @Fredy I am speaking from experience here since I have been doing geometry with C# since VS2002 (Framework 1.1).

Comment: @JAlex Thank you for your point of view. It's weird that a library containing the relevant algorithms has not been released. I saw many things on the web about this intersection thing. Some seemed to be optimized.

Comment: @Fredy - Did you look at https://www.geometrictools.com/

Comment: @JAlex it's impressive! Thanks for this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Intersection test between two line segments

[image: fig1]

```text
Segment A: [<1, 7>-<2, -1>]
Segment B: [<-2, 1>-<6, 4>]
Segments A, B intersect at <1.58209, 2.343284>.
```

[image: fig2]

```text
Segment A: [<1, 7>-<2, -1>]
Segment B: [<2, 2>-<6, 4>]
Segments A, B do not intersect.
```

### Summary

There are two parts to this process.

1. Extend the lines to infinity and see where (and if) they intersect.

   - Form the lines using `(a,b,c)` coordinates with equations `a*x+b*y+c=0`. These are the homogeneous coordinates of a line.
   - Find the homogeneous coordinates of the point where two lines meet.
2. Check if the intersection point is contained within a line segment.

   - Project the point on the line. This step can be omitted in this case because by definition the point is common to both lines.
   - Find the distance ratio `t` of the point along the distance `A` to `B`. If `t=0` then the point is at `A`, if `t=100%` then the point is at `B` and if `t=50%` then the point is at the midpoint of `AB`. The point is contained in the segment if `t>=0` and `t<=1`.

<sub>Note on nomenclature. A line is an infinite line, and a line segment is the line defined between two points.</sub>

### Details

The crux of the procedure above is implemented inside the `LineeSegment.TryIntersect()` method.

#### Program

The use used to generate the tests above. `GeometryTools` is a static class containing helpful methods and values.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var segA = new LineSegment(
            new Vector2(1, 7),
            new Vector2(2, -1));

        var segB = new LineSegment(
            new Vector2(-2, 1),
            new Vector2(6, 4));

        Console.WriteLine($"Segment A: {segA}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Segment B: {segB}");

        if (segA.TryIntersect(segB, out Vector2 point))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Segments A, B intersect at {point}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Segments A, B do not intersect.");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Line Segment

The code above depends on a class `LineSegment` that is defined from two points, and the function `TryIntersect()` which checks if two line segments intersect.

```
public readonly struct LineSegment
{
    public LineSegment(Vector2 from, Vector2 to) : this()
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }

    public Vector2 From { get; }
    public Vector2 To { get; }

    public float Length { get => Vector2.Distance(From, To); }
    public Vector2 Direction { get => Vector2.Normalize(To - From); }
    public Vector2 Normal { get => Vector2.Normalize(new Vector2(-(To.Y - From.Y), (To.X - From.X))); }

    public bool IsFinite
    {
        get => !float.IsNaN(From.X) && !float.IsNaN(From.Y)
            && !float.IsNaN(To.X) && !float.IsNaN(To.Y);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if a point is contained within the line segment
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Contains(Vector2 target, bool inclusive = true)
    {
        if (TryJoin(From, To, out var line))
        {
            target = line.Project(target);
            Vector2 dir = Direction;
            float t = Vector2.Dot(dir, target - From) / Vector2.Dot(dir, To - From);
            return inclusive ? t >= 0 && t <= 1 : t > TINY && t < 1 - TINY;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Try to intersect two line segments
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">The other line segment.</param>
    /// <param name="point">The intersection point.</param>
    /// <returns>True if they intersect, False otherwise</returns>
    public bool TryIntersect(LineSegment other, out Vector2 point, bool inclusive = true)
    {
        point = Vector2.Zero;

        if (GeometryTools.TryJoin(From, To, out InfiniteLine thisLine) 
            && GeometryTools.TryJoin(other.From, other.To, out InfiniteLine otherLine))
        {
            if (GeometryTools.TryMeet(thisLine, otherLine, out point))
            {
                return Contains(point, inclusive) && other.Contains(point, inclusive);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public override string ToString() => $"[{From}-{To}]";
}
```

#### Infinite Line

It is helpful to group the parameters and properties of an infinte line into a class.

```
public readonly struct InfiniteLine
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The line at the horizon (not on the Eucledian plane).
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly InfiniteLine Horizon = new InfiniteLine(0, 0, 1);

    public InfiniteLine(float a, float b, float c) : this()
    {
        this.Coeff = (a, b, c);
        float m = (float)Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b);
        this.IsFinite = m > GeometryTools.TINY;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The (a,b,c) coefficients define a line by the equation: <code>a*x+b*y+c=0</code>
    /// </summary>
    public (float a, float b, float c) Coeff { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// True if line is in finite space, False if line is at horizon.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsFinite { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if point belongs to the infinite line.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="point">The target point.</param>
    /// <returns>True if point is one the line.</returns>
    public bool Contains(Vector2 point)
    {
        return IsFinite 
            && Math.Abs(Coeff.a * point.X + Coeff.b * point.Y + Coeff.c) <= TINY;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Projects a target point onto the line.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target">The target point.</param>
    /// <returns>The point on the line closest to the target.</returns>
    /// <remarks>If line is not finite the resulting point has NaN or Inf coordinates.</remarks>
    public Vector2 Project(Vector2 target)
    {
        (float a, float b, float c) = Coeff;
        float m2 = a * a + b * b;
        float px = b * (b * target.X - a * target.Y) - a * c;
        float py = a * (a * target.Y - b * target.X) - b * c;
        return new Vector2(px / m2, py / m2);
    }
    public override string ToString() => $"({Coeff.a})*x+({Coeff.b})*y+({Coeff.c})=0";
}
```

#### Geometry Tools

Helper function that define a line from two points (meet), or define a point from two lines (join). But in Euclidian geometry these operations might fail (parallel lines, or coincident points) so they are designed here to return `true`/`false` values accordingly.

```
public static class GeometryTools
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The value of 2^-19 is tiny
    /// </summary>
    public const float TINY = 1f / 524288;

    /// <summary>
    /// Try to join two points with an infinite line.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="A">The first point.</param>
    /// <param name="B">The second point.</param>
    /// <param name="line">The line joining the two points.</param>
    /// <returns>False if the two points are coincident, True otherwise.</returns>
    public static bool TryJoin(Vector2 A, Vector2 B, out InfiniteLine line)
    {
        float dx = B.X - A.X, dy = B.Y - A.Y;
        float m = A.X * B.Y - A.Y * B.X;
        line = new InfiniteLine(-dy, dx, m);
        return line.IsFinite;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Try to find the point where two infinite lines meet.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="L">The fist line.</param>
    /// <param name="M">The second line.</param>
    /// <param name="point">The point where the two lines meet.</param>
    /// <returns>False if the two lines are parallel, True othrwise.</returns>
    public static bool TryMeet(InfiniteLine L, InfiniteLine M, out Vector2 point)
    {
        (float a1, float b1, float c1) = L.Coeff;
        (float a2, float b2, float c2) = M.Coeff;
        float d = a1 * b2 - a2 * b1;
        if (d != 0)
        {
            point = new Vector2((b1 * c2 - b2 * c1) / d, (a2 * c1 - a1 * c2) / d);
            return true;
        }
        point = Vector2.Zero;
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Exclude End Points

If by default the `Contains()` and `TryIntersect()` methods include the end points in the calculations. But with the opional parameter set to `inclusive = false` you can exclude end points.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var segA = new LineSegment(
            new Vector2(1, 5),
            new Vector2(2, 2));

        var segB = new LineSegment(
            new Vector2(2, 2),
            new Vector2(6, 4));

        Console.WriteLine($"Segment A: {segA}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Segment B: {segB}");

        if (segA.TryIntersect(segB, out Vector2 point, false))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Segments A, B intersect at {point}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Segments A, B do not intersect.");
        }
    }
}
```

See the example below

[image: fig3]

with output

```text
Segment A: [<1, 5>-<2, 2>]
Segment B: [<2, 2>-<6, 4>]
Segments A, B do not intersect.
```

This means that you can use `A.TryIntersect(B, out var point, false)` to specify if endpoints would count as a collision or not.

<sub>The code above is far from optimized as it calls several functions many times over and over, instead of caching the results and using them. It is for illustrative purposes to explain the process step by step.</sub>

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the need to include or exclude the end points of a line segment in the check.

Comment: thank you so much, I'll test it today to see if this indeed is where I'm going wrong!

Comment: I've implemented it and still run into the same issue but through testing I know for sure that your provided solution is correct. There must be something wrong with my implementation after getting the lines. Thanks for your extensive explanation, really helped understanding the theory of it and the unit test!